# How to quickly add a Wordpress blog to an existing RoR app without writing a custom blogging ror app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress

This question is related to [Creating a Blog in an Existing Ruby on Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222957/creating-a-blog-in-an-existing-ruby-on-rails-app), but it doesn't have the answer I am looking for.

I have put a `blog` folder in my existing ror app's `public` with a hope that I can get to my blog by `http://example.com/blog` or during local test I could access it through `http://localhost:3000/blog`  (`localhost:3000` where I can access my original app)

But, I get following error

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/blog"

Try running rake routes
```

What line should I add my `routes.rb` or `vhost` files on server to get what I want?

The blog folder has fully functional wordpress blogging system.

I am not a Ruby on Rails expert, the app was created by someone else, I was looking for some quick work around to add the blog.

I certainly don't want to create a subdomain `http://blog.example.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with running Wordpress inside a Rails app is that Wordpress runs on PHP.  I'm not sure if there is an elegant solution for serving PHP inside Rails (you may just be able to point Apache to the directory inside your Rails app, I don't know), but it seems like a bad idea, or at least a huge pain.

What I would do is serve your Wordpress blog along side your Rails app (so you've got a PHP and a Rails server running), and just have your `/blog` route point to a controller that redirects to your Wordpress app.  Add something like this to your `routes.rb`:

```
get '/blog', to: 'blog#redirect'
```

and then have a `redirect` method in your `BlogController` that simply does this:

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
    def redirect
        redirect_to "url_of_wordpress_blog"
    end
end
```

Now you can point at `yourdomain.com/blog` and it will take you to the Wordpress site.

Comment: +1 thanks!,sounds easy to do. I will test this out in the the evening.

Comment: question, what would be `"url_of_wordpress_blog"` should I move my `blog` folder from ror's `app/public` to somewhere else? Will I still able to access my blog post like `http://mydomain.com/blog/a-blog-post.htm`

Comment: Yes, you should move it to `/var/www` or wherever your Apache server looks for a PHP site.

Comment: Hi @Watt, what would be the value of 'url_of_wordpress_blog' or how can I find it?